# AJAX PHP Login code does not work

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to put together an ajax login, After putting the code together yesterday the ajax login was functioning perfectly well. However, today a few issues have risen where the ajax would not login at all.

The code has not been touched since.

After looking at the console, i cannot seem to locate and debug the error.

All help appreciated

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Juicy Juice | Buy a range of different juice</title>
</head>
    <body>

        <div id="container">
            <div id="custLogin">
                <a href="login.php">Login</a>
                <a href="register.php">Register</a>
            </div>

            <div id="logo">LOGO HERE</div>

            <!-- Navigation Bar Start-->

            <div id="nav">
                <a href="index.php">HOME</a>
                <a href="about.php">ABOUT</a>
                <a href="products.php">PRODUCTS</a>
                <a href="contact.php">CONTACT</a>
                    <div id="searchbox">
                        <form action="results.php" method="get">
                          <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="name" required>
                          <input id="button" type="submit" value="GO"></input>
                        </form>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Navigation Bar End-->              

            <!-- Login header -->
            <h1>Login</h1>

            <!--Login Form -->

            <div id="loginContainer">
                <form>
                    <label for="emailLogin">Email Address</label>
                     <input id="emailLogin" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email">

                    <label for="passLogin">Password</label>
                      <input id="passLogin" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password">         

                    <button onclick="login()">Login</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        <p style="color: red" id="ErrorMessages"></p>


        <script>
        //Global variables 
        var loggedInStr = "Logged in <button onclick='logout()'>Logout</button>";
        var loginStr = document.getElementById("custLogin").innerHTML;
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        //Check login when page loads
        window.onload = checkLogin;

        //Checks whether user is logged in.
        function checkLogin(){
            //Create event handler that specifies what should happen when server responds
            request.onload = function(){
                if(request.responseText === "ok"){
                    document.getElementById("custLogin").innerHTML = loggedInStr;
                }
                else{
                    console.log(request.responseText);
                    document.getElementById("custLogin").innerHTML  = loginStr;
                }
            };
            //Set up and send request
            request.open("GET", "check_login.php");
            request.send();
        }

        //Attempts to log in user to server
        function login(){
            //Create event handler that specifies what should happen when server responds
            request.onload = function(){
                //Check HTTP status code
                if(request.status === 200){
                    //Get data from server
                    var responseData = request.responseText;

                    //Add data to page
                    if(responseData === "ok"){
                        document.getElementById("custLogin").innerHTML = loggedInStr;
                        document.getElementById("ErrorMessages").innerHTML = "";//Clear error messages
                    }
                    else
                        document.getElementById("ErrorMessages").innerHTML = request.responseText;
                }
                else
                    document.getElementById("ErrorMessages").innerHTML = "Error communicating with server";
            };

            //Extract login data
            var usrEmail = document.getElementById("emailLogin").value;
            var usrPassword = document.getElementById("passLogin").value;

            //Set up and send request
            request.open("POST", "customer_login.php");
            request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.send("email=" + usrEmail + "&password=" + usrPassword);
        }

        //Logs the user out.
        function logout(){
            //Create event handler that specifies what should happen when server responds
            request.onload = function(){
                checkLogin();
            };
            //Set up and send request
            request.open("GET", "logout.php");
            request.send();
        }

    </script>


        <!-- Footer Start-->

            <div id="footer">
                <div id="bottomNav">
                    <a class="active" href="index.html">HOME</a> |
                    <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a> |
                    <a href="products.html">PRODUCTS</a> |
                    <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
                </div>
                    Copyright © 2018 | Juicy Juice
            </div>


        </div>
        <!-- Footer End-->
    </body>
```

PHP code (3 separate files)

```
<?php
//Start session management
session_start();

if( array_key_exists("loggedInUserEmail", $_SESSION) ){
}
else{
    echo 'Not logged in.';
}



<?php

//Start session management
session_start();

//Get name and address strings - need to filter input to reduce chances of SQL injection etc.
$email= filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);    

//Connect to MongoDB and select database
$mongoClient = new MongoClient();
$db = $mongoClient->juice;

//Create a PHP array with our search criteria
$findCriteria = [
    "email" => $email
 ];

//Find all of the customers that match  this criteria
$cursor = $db->customers->find($findCriteria);

//Check that there is exactly one customer
if($cursor->count() == 0){
    echo 'Email not recognized.';
    return;
}
else if($cursor->count() > 1){
    echo 'Database error: Multiple customers have same email address.';
    return;
}

//Get customer
$customer = $cursor->getNext();

//Check password
if($customer['password'] != $password){
    echo 'Password incorrect.';
    return;
}

//Start session for this user
$_SESSION['loggedInUserEmail'] = $email;

//Inform web page that login is successful
echo 'ok';  

//Close the connection
$mongoClient->close();


<?php
//Start session management
session_start();

//Remove all session variables
session_unset(); 

//Destroy the session 
session_destroy(); 

//Echo result to user
echo 'ok';
```

Javascript (AJAX)

```
<script>
        //Global variables 
        var loggedInStr = "Logged in <button onclick='logout()'>Logout</button>";
        var loginStr = document.getElementById("custLogin").innerHTML;
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        //Check login when page loads
        window.onload = checkLogin;

        //Checks whether user is logged in.
        function checkLogin(){
            //Create event handler that specifies what should happen when server responds
            request.onload = function(){
                if(request.responseText === "ok"){
                    document.getElementById("custLogin").innerHTML = loggedInStr;
                }
                else{
                    console.log(request.responseText);
                    document.getElementById("custLogin").innerHTML  = loginStr;
                }
            };
            //Set up and send request
            request.open("GET", "check_login.php");
            request.send();
        }

        //Attempts to log in user to server
        function login(){
            //Create event handler that specifies what should happen when server responds
            request.onload = function(){
                //Check HTTP status code
                if(request.status === 200){
                    //Get data from server
                    var responseData = request.responseText;

                    //Add data to page
                    if(responseData === "ok"){
                        document.getElementById("custLogin").innerHTML = loggedInStr;
                        document.getElementById("ErrorMessages").innerHTML = "";//Clear error messages
                    }
                    else
                        document.getElementById("ErrorMessages").innerHTML = request.responseText;
                }
                else
                    document.getElementById("ErrorMessages").innerHTML = "Error communicating with server";
            };

            //Extract login data
            var usrEmail = document.getElementById("emailLogin").value;
            var usrPassword = document.getElementById("passLogin").value;

            //Set up and send request
            request.open("POST", "customer_login.php");
            request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.send("email=" + usrEmail + "&password=" + usrPassword);
        }

        //Logs the user out.
        function logout(){
            //Create event handler that specifies what should happen when server responds
            request.onload = function(){
                checkLogin();
            };
            //Set up and send request
            request.open("GET", "logout.php");
            request.send();
        }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if there is no javascript error in your console:

1. check your console for "xhr" request for customer_login.php
2. at the login.php file print the email and password to make sure that you got them right
3. check your query for error
4. check your session to see what you got

I hope that these steps will help you find the problem